# No details error on $.ajax request (crossdomain)

Tags: jquery, ajax

Any hints? This is my code:

```
var url = window.CANILE_BASE_URL + 'v2/canile/?location_lat=' + lat + '&location_lng=' + lng;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        alert(1);
        var accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    }
}).success(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
}).fail(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

And this is the firebug response:
[image]

Comment: is there a error code? (500, 404, 403?)

Comment: Seems that the request is not starting… because I don't see in firebug:
GET https://api.mydomain.com/v2/etc…

the question is WHY?

Comment: did you tried jsonp (i assume that you know about cross domain limitations of browsers.)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross+domain

Comment: Yes i know, the fact is this:
Another request on another endpoint is starting and working correctly.

The problem on this request is that is not starting, imho.

Comment: Ok, another details in my backend server log I see:

[08/Jan/2013 03:40:08] "OPTIONS /v2/canile/?location_lat=43.7878252&location_lng=11.3939682 HTTP/1.1" 401 269

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22372/discussion-between-beddamadre-and-lupus)